Freeness of a quotient module over a regular local ring
Let $R$ be a regular local ring with maximal ideal $m$. Let $t\in m\setminus m^2$. Let $N$ be a submodule of a finitely generated free $R$-module $M$ satisfying
$$ tM \subseteq N \subseteq M.$$
Question: If $N$ is free over $R$, is $M/N$ also free over $R/tR$?
Remark: This is true in case $\mathrm{rank}(M)=1$. Because there is no principal ideal $I$ satisfying
$$(t) \subsetneq I \subsetneq R.$$

Here is one possible way of seeing this (this is heavily inspired by an argument in Zhu's affine grassmannian notes). Choose a sequence of elements $t_1, t_2 \ldots t_n$ in $m\setminus m^2$ such that $(t=t_0, t_1, \ldots t_n)$ is a regular sequence of parameters. We want to show that $Tor^i(M/N, R/(t_1, t_2, \ldots, t_n))=0$ for all $i>0$. We have a short exact sequence
$$0 \to M/N \to M[t^{-1}]/N \to M[t^{-1}]/M \to 0$$
Now, we have canonical identifications of localizations $M[t^{-1}] = N[t^{-1}]$ by the assumption $tM \subset N$. Therefore, by the short exact sequence above and the freeness of $N$ and $M$, we are reduced to showing the corresponding vanishing of higher Tors for $M[t^{-1}]/M \cong N[t^{-1}]/N \cong (R[t^{-1}]/R)^{\oplus rk(M)}$.
But now $R[t^{-1}]/R$ is a filtered colimit of the modules $t^{-n}R/R$, which are iterated extensions of the module $R/(t)$, for which the desired Tor vanishing is clear.

Yes, because it is a maximal Cohen--Macaulay module over a regular local ring.

Sasha, why it is maximal CM, and why maxiamal CM implies freeness, could you please explain a little more, or give me some reference? Thanks!

The first is, essentially, by definition. For the second see https://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/00NT.
